# Integrating NUnit to test asynchronous web services in windows phone 7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, nunit, assertion

I am trying to integrate NUnit in my windows phone project to test asynchronous web service calls. I am referring to NUnitTestRunnerWP7 dll. Here is what I did.

But the asynchronous callback method is called after the Assert statement, hence it does not work. How can I execute the Assert after my callback? If I write the failed Assertion in callback, my application crashes.

```
[Test]
public void TestAsyncFunc(){
        string result;
        ManualResetEvent manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        MyWebServiceClient client = GetMyWebServiceClient(); //added a service reference for asmx services
        client.LoginCompleted += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            result = args.Result.ToString();
            manualReset.Set();
        };
        client.LoginAsync("username", "password");
        if (!manualReset.WaitOne(5000))
            Assert.Fail();

        Assert.AreEqual("", result);
    }
```

I don't understand what am I missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.